# Why does dhcpcd flood my logs with with useless messages when I use the `inform` option?

Tags: networking, debug, dhcpcd

In accordance with `man dhcpcd.conf` I used the `inform` option to set a static IP address. Using this option seems to cause my DHCP *client* `dhcpcd` to flood my logfile with *useless* messages. Here is a sample:

```bsh
# After adding line: `inform 192.168.1.199/24` to `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` on my wifi interface # and rebooting, `journalctl` is showing approx *8 log entries per second*: 

$ journalctl -f | grep wlan0
Mar 26 07:15:17 raspberrypi0w dhcpcd[568]: wlan0: received approval for 192.168.1.199
Mar 26 07:15:17 raspberrypi0w dhcpcd[568]: wlan0: received approval for 192.168.1.199
Mar 26 07:15:17 raspberrypi0w dhcpcd[568]: wlan0: received approval for 192.168.1.199
... ad infinitum at a rate of 4-8 per second
```

The `request` option (similar to `inform`) exhibits no such behavior. Before choosing my static IP, I reviewed the settings of the DHCP server for my network: I verified that my chosen IP address was ***not*** an active lease. I even took the additional (but unnecessary) step of choosing an IP address that was outside the available range/pool of dynamic addresses configured on my DHCP server.

My system is `bullseye`, and `dhcpcd` version is `8.1.2`. `buster` uses the same version of `dhcpcd`, and exhibits the same behavior. And same behavior for wired (eth0) and wireless (`wlan0`) interfaces.

What is the problem, and how do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/NetworkConfiguration/dhcpcd ? Ray Marples was very helpful but contracted cancer and passed the task on.

Comment: @Milliways: Yes, [I did](https://github.com/NetworkConfiguration/dhcpcd/pull/95) - note Roy's comment, *`"But this doesn't really help downstreams to update dhcpcd :("`*. More details [here](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/FixDhcpcd.md) ICYI. And yeah - I only learned of his cancer earlier today - it was a shock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have found a ***bug***. This bug has a *history*. I won't go into the details here; you can read the following posts if you're interested: [Feb 18, 2020](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=265516&sid=0b39d514c0f941e9516980ef66394e2e), [Aug 16, 2021](https://github.com/NetworkConfiguration/dhcpcd/issues/47), [Mar 30, 2022](https://github.com/NetworkConfiguration/dhcpcd/issues/94), [April 4, 2022](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/4360#issuecomment-1087715222).

I gather from the exchange on [April 4, 2022](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/4360#issuecomment-1087715222), that Raspberry Pi has no *established* channel for submitting pull/merge requests to the `dhcpcd` sources they maintain. <strike>But I feel sure that</strike> [I'm not sure the information passed on to the RPi organization in that post](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/repo/issues/300) will eventually yield an *upgrade* through the `apt` process. In either case, I've [posted a *"recipe"* for downloading, "patching" and building `dhcpcd`](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/FixDhcpcd.md) without this annoying little bug.

FWIW, I've tested it on 3 of my systems (2 bullseye & 1 buster). It certainly eliminates the logging issues, and I've noticed no other side effects. Also, the coding change strikes me as a simple one, but you may make your own judgments on that point.

Comment: According to Seamus' comments in https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/137443/dhcpcd-conf-inform-vs-static-ip-vs-request-how-should-you-really-setup-a-static, this bug should have been fixed in recent Raspbians.