# How to open PI for network traffic on a schedule

Tags: raspbian, python, networking, cron

In an attempt to reduce risk to an IOT device I'd like it to enable wifi on a schedule, say only between 00:00 and 00:03 every day. Only just enough to upload a log file to my server, and then disable the networking again for 24 hours.

Is there a simple config or tool to help me set that up? Or is it easily scripted in python or such if I set it on a CRON job?

Comment: Raspberry Pi is irrelevant to your question ... please ask at a linux site

Comment: You can plug the WiFi into a timer and let it turn it on and off.

Comment: Hello Matt & welcome to RPi SE. As you're probably aware, there are several methods in Linux that can be used to disable a network interface. ***Which*** method to use will depend (in part) on the network manager being used. You've tagged your question w/ `raspbian`, so that narrows the range, but just to be clear, would you please confirm that you're using the default `dhcpcd` as your network manager?

Comment: Matt - Are you still with us, or is this no longer of interest, or have you found another solution, or...?

Answer (score 1):

One way (not necessarily the *best* way) to disable `wlan0` on your RPi is with `rfkill`. Before going further, I should state the obvious for clarity: **Once you've disabled `wlan0`, it cannot be used to communicate with the device.** So - if `wlan0` is your **only** interface, you will need to do some planing; i.e. how to connect to your RPi in the absence of `wlan0`.

That said, here's a `cron` job that should do what you want:

Since `rfkill` typically requires `root` privileges, we'll use `root`'s `crontab` for this:

```bash
$ sudo crontab -e

# root crontab opens in your chosen default editor...
```

The following `crontab` entries should toggle `wlan0` ON at midnight (local time), and OFF again 3 minutes later:

```
0 0 * * * /usr/sbin/rfkill unblock wlan0 
3 0 * * * /usr/sbin/rfkill block wlan0
```

Save your `crontab` & exit the editor. That should meet your minimum requirement; I'll leave it to you to embellish the `crontab` entries for output redirection - or development of a script to perform any related tasks.

You may also wish to consider how to handle things following a `reboot`. Let us know if you have further questions.

Comment: What's wrong with `systemd [stop|start] dhcpcd`?

Comment: @goldilocks: Probably nothing; what's wrong with `rfkill`?  :)

Comment: It just seems hacky in the sense that there's no contract w/ dhcpcd (or whatever service is managing networking) to guarantee this doesn't have unintended side effects.  A sloppy analogy: Q: How should I park my car? A: Leave it in gear with the front wheels against the curb.   This will *probably* work fine, but it is not, as we say, a "canonical answer".   OTOH, using the "proper method" doesn't guarantee some other service for whatever reason won't restart networking.  With that in mind :D I'd stop dhcpcd and block w/ rfkill.

Comment: @goldilocks: If I *knew* of any unintended side effects, I wouldn't have chosen it as my answer. TBH, I thought of 3 possible answers: `systemd`, `wpa_cli` and `rfkill`. The OP asked for `"simple"`; I thought this was *simplest*. I did say it might not be the "best" way, because "best" often varies based on details which we don't know. Wrt a "contract", `rfkill` is part of the kernel, so that seems fairly solid to me. So that's my thinking, but I'm always interested in learning something new. And oddly (to me), 4 voters have opined this Q was off-topic - what do you think?

Comment: TBH I though about this a little afterward and it is mebbe more elegant than hacky ;)  WRT "side effects", though, I meant eg., what might happen with `dhcpcd` if it was left running; an rfkill block will I assume (haven't checked) result in "no carrier" on the wifi interface, and other userland things may respond to that.  However, dhcpcd is reasonably sane and even if it were a problem (I would want to test this somewhere convenient before deploying it in the wild), that should be fixable via configuration.

Comment: @goldilocks: First, some [comic relief](https://giphy.com/gifs/twinpeaksonshowtime-season-2-twin-peaks-3og0IQVQ5YwY6Lwk6c).  [`dhcpcd` isn't perfect](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/137113/83790), but it's pretty good - esp considering the changes to the DHCP "standards" over the years. I don't think it'll go on strike, but may generate some additional log traffic. I'd love to see an answer here that handled this situation using `dhcpcd-run-hooks` and `wpa_cli`. I also wonder about power consumption - does `rfkill` cause wifi hdwe to consume less power than alternatives?